# OLE registration database access with Iron Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ole, comtypes, running-object-table

I am trying to extract an active object using comtypes module:

```
import comtypes.client as cc
table = cc.GetActiveObject()
```

but its throwing an error saying that it needs at least one argument. I think its the OLE Registration database key but i am not sure how to extract it. Is there a way to look up currently registered applications and query their key/name so that i can get the active object?

thanks!